# Ubuntu 10.04 using ssh without entering my password

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, passwords

I know questions like this have been asked before, and I have read them all (that I found).

The problem I have is that we have an embedded linux device that we can log into for debug purposes by doing the following:

```
ssh root@name
```

Then the password is anything (I usually just hit enter). I don't want to change anything on the embedded device/linux. But I do want to be able to (as part of my script) ssh into it.

My research has shown me that the following can be used (this is copied from another post):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

However with my version of Ubuntu (10.04) I don't have spawn or send commands. I was able to install the "expect" command with sudo apt-get install expect.

Does anyone have a solution? is it possible to install these commands, or is there another way to ssh and get past the "password" step?

Thanks :)

------------- EDIT -----------------

I think I am starting to understand the issue I am having. I have a script that starts with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then later I am trying to do:

```
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

I did not realise that you needed explicitly the:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

At the start of the script. so I have had to move my code into a seperate file which contains only and exactly:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@my.server.com
expect "assword:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

... sorry for the mis-understanding on my part, but people answers helped me to twig what I was doing. This is not quite ideal for me as I wanted to pass parameters in to open different ssh connections and I can't pass in parameters to this script starting with "expect -f"
 :(

Comment: Is there any reason you can not use a ssh key?  Such as not being able to write to /root? If not please read [this](http://linuxconfig.org/passwordless-ssh).

Comment: and the spawn and send are internal cmds to expect. Once you have it installed correctly, you should be able to above script. Good luck.

Comment: @Hennes Actually in this case "yes" there is a reason I can't do that. The embedded linux file system is read only (proceted). Though I can unlock this everything will be over-written when we install the next version (which is very often :( ... but the solution looks good for a future use :)

Comment: I expect as much when I read "embedded". Otherwise I would just have commented "Upgrade it to something more modern and use ssh keys".  (Q: Overwritten as read from flash and unpacked to RAM or union FS?)

Comment: @shellter Hmm... as I mentioned I did sudo apt-get install expect. But send still does not work. I get error like `program 'send' can be found in the following packages: mailutils-mh, nmh`. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: @Hennes The entire flash is over-written via a USB deployment when in u-boot. So the whole kernel is updated.

Comment: Added an edit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to run your script as a shell script. After installing `expect`, run your script like this:

```
expect -f scrip.exp
```

If you can't install expect as a normal user, try installing its binaries in one of your directories in `$HOME` e.g. `$HOME/opt/` and call `expect` from there, although it would depend on your system on how you could manipulate `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add another directory for searching dynamic libraries.

An example of embedded expect:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=$1
SERVER=$2
PASSWORD=$3

expect <<EOF
spawn ssh "${USER}@${SERVER}"
expect "assword:"
send "${PASSWORD}\r"
interact
EOF
```

Run with

```
bash script.sh user server password
```

Comment: Thanks for that, your reply helped my to understand what I was doing wrong. Please see my edit.

Comment: @code_fodder Please see my update.