# expect command in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, expect

I've searched all over SuperUser, but couldn't get the solution.
Here is a script that am using for ssh using `expect`. I'm using ubuntu and I've installed expect using `aptitude install expect`.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh user@server
expect "Password:"
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

When I run this script file, sh script.sh, I'm getting this error,

```
test.sh: 3: spawn: not found
couldn't read file "Password:": no such file or directory
test.sh: 5: send: not found
test.sh: 6: interact: not found
```

I've tried with this posts, but not working,
[Ubuntu 10.04 using ssh without entering my password](https://superuser.com/questions/646957/ubuntu-10-04-using-ssh-without-entering-my-password)

Thanks,

Comment: How are you running the script exactly? (Exact thing you type on the command line.)

Comment: I use user name, server name and password in the file itself. So no input parameters. Then i run the file 'script.sh' as `sh script.sh`

Comment: You're specifically asking the shell to run your script. Make it executable (chmod +x ./script.sh) then run it (./script.sh). And don't call an expect script `.sh`, that's confusing - it's not a shell script.

Comment: @Mat, thanks a lot. I've given execute permission and ran it as `./script.sh`. And right, it's not a shell script. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your file executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

and run it like:

```
./script.sh
```